# Environmental economics problem: how to think to find law of motion and objective function?

Tags: optimization, economics, dynamic-programming

I'm reading an interesting book on mathematical economics written by a German professor. It contains many theory chapters and exercises, but not all of them have the solution at the end of the book. One of these exercises is the following and I would like to ask how to think in order to find law of motions and objective functions in these kind of problems.

"Imagine you are an economist only interested in maximizing the present value of
your endowment. You own a renewable resource, for example a piece of forest. The
amount of wood in your forest at a point in time $t$ is given by $x_t$. Trees grow at
$b(x_t)$ and you harvest at $t$ the quantity $c_t$.

(a) What is the law of motion for $x_t$?

(b) What is your objective function if prices at t per unit of wood is given by $p_t$,
your horizon is infinity and you have perfect information?

(c) How much should you harvest per period when the interest rate is constant?
Does this change when the interest rate is time-variable?"

When I thought about the law of motion of $x_t$ I find difficult to link $b(x_t)$ and the unknown law of motion together, but I tried with $b(x_t)=x_t-c_t$. Next question is related to the objective function and I tried with $U_t=\sum_{\tau=t}^\infty=\beta^{(\tau-t)}\cdot p_\tau\cdot x_\tau$

I don't know how to go further, because I'm not really into this kind of stuff.

Thanks for your possible help.

Comment: I am by a longshot no economist, but it seems like the "law of motion" would be better expressed as the following differential equation $$ x_t'(t) = b(x_t) - c_t  $$ where $c_t$ would need to be the rate at which we are taking wood from the forest. This mathematical statement would then be "the rate of change of wood is equal to the rate at which the trees grow minus the rate at which we remove wood." Please do correct me if this doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: @vb628 ok thanks, this exercise belongs to a chapter where there aren't exercises in continuos time, so I think I shouldn't use the formula you wrote, but it let me think about a possibile difference equation, useful for the problem: $b(x_t)=x_t-c_t-(x_{t-1}-c_{t-1})$ . Please tell me if it seems wrong.